# Apple push notification service for MDM

Tags: ssl, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I've read a tutorial about Apple push notification
[here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Due to it, I have to provide App Id to identify which application will receive the notification.
In case of MDM server, the receiver is built-in client, so what value I have to put in field "App Id" when I register for SSL certificate

on another question I've post, I was answered that in case of MDM, the field "Topic" is used for built-in client to receive the notification. Topic is put in MDM payload that server sent to client. So how server register this field with APNS

Thank all,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You don't go through usual push certificate creation route.

What you do is following

- You create a CSR for APNS request signging certificate
- You send it to Apple and Apple will sign it, so you will have APNS request signing certificate
- Each custom will create APNS CSR and send it to you
- You will sign it with APNS request signing certificate
- You will return this  APNS CSR to the customer
- The customer will upload it to Apple
- Apple will sign it
- Now, the customer has APNS certificate
- The customer uploads it to the MDM server

All of these is described in a lengthy details in MDM protocol documentaion.

2)Here is how topic is shared between a client and the server

- APNS certificate signed by apple will have a topic in it (in UID part of DN)
- Your MDM server should extract it from APNS certificate and put it in MDM payload.
- This payload will be delievered to a device and OS will send it to buil-it client
- Now, both your server and built-in client know the shared topic.

Comment: could you please check this, https://stackoverflow.com/q/44886700/3145189